# Ubuntu install on Chromebook using codestarter script stalling at updates

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromebook

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my chromebook (acer 720) using the codestarter script here https://github.com/codestarterorg/ubuntu-chromebook-installer.   It seems to be stalling on the portion of the install script that has to do with installing updates.  I see the message "Installing updates..." from the script but then nothing happens after that.

```
log_msg "INFO" "Installing updates..."
run_command_chroot "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get -y -q update"
run_command_chroot "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get -y -q upgrade"
```

As near as I can tell from the chrome task manager nothing is happening - no network activity and almost no cpu use.

Advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait longer.  "Installing updates" took almost 2 hours for me.

I got in touch with Codestarter on Twitter. Below is their reply:

> It usually takes 60-90 minutes depending on the speed of your internet connection (it needs to download a ~1GB Ubuntu image.)